# Facebook "fbs_APP_ID" cookie issues

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I recently started to work with the Facebook API and I'm have some problems with showing the $_COOKIE["fbs_APP_ID"] cookie. Even when I log in with facebook and reload the same page the cookie is still showing null.

Here is my code.  I took out my app id for security purposes but just assume that I have put it down in my real script.

By the way, I have in fact registered my application on facebook and such.

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>My Facebook Login Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>

  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : 'APP_ID',
        status     : true, 
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true,
        oauth      : true,
      });

        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response){
            window.location.reload();
            document.getElementById("messageContainer").innerHTML = "Reloaded successfully!";
        });

    };

    (function(d){
       var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
       d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
     }(document));
  </script>

  <div class="fb-login-button">Login with Facebook</div>
  <div id = "messageContainer"> </div>
  <div id = "cookieCheck"> <?php echo var_dump($_COOKIE["fbs_APP_ID"]) ?></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on oauth2 you will get cookie by $_COOKIE["fbsr_APP_ID"]  not fbs..

if you want to get access_token use response:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
   if (response.status === 'connected') { 
    var access_token=response.authResponse.accessToken
   };
})
```

Comment: Sweet, thanks it worked.  If you don't mind me asking, I had 'oauth' set to true. why is oauth2 the one is used?

Comment: no problem. yes, oauth must be true. Facebook upgraded oauth protocol to 2.0. then somethings changed on api and sdks.
eg: we must use "scope" instead "perms" now. keep in mind.

Comment: All right, thanks.  First time really using the Facebook API.  They probably should update their tutorials, then.